# Why is my Datetime Object Being Converted To Unicode

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I have written a program that picks out relevant information from a SQL table and presents that information in a Pandas DataFrame. I am attempting to create my own table for testing purposes but the DataFrame is converting my Datetime objects to Unicode.

The following code builds the table:

```
def launcher():
    curr_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    conn = db = sqlite3.Connection("test.db")
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE test(begin_ts, process_name, count, name)")

    values = OrderedDict()
    values[datetime.datetime.strptime('{0} 07:00:00'.format(curr_date), DATE_FORMAT)] = 10
    values[datetime.datetime.strptime('{0} 10:00:00'.format(curr_date), DATE_FORMAT)] = 123456
    values[datetime.datetime.strptime('{0} 13:00:00'.format(curr_date), DATE_FORMAT)] = 75682
    values[datetime.datetime.strptime('{0} 16:00:00'.format(curr_date), DATE_FORMAT)] = 789545
    values[datetime.datetime.strptime('{0} 20:00:00'.format(curr_date), DATE_FORMAT)] = 25469

    test_values = []
    for x in range(1, 4):
        for time, tps in values.items():
            print("Time is of type {0} in the table".format(type(time)))
            test_values.append((time, 'matching_{0}_gw'.format(x), tps))
            values[time] = tps + 30

    for elem in test_values:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'raw_msg_count')", [elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]])

    print(db.execute("SELECT * FROM test").fetchall())

    return conn
```

The following code is the DataFrame code:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(self.query(), database)  # self.query() is just a query that picks out the relevant information
for elem in df.begin_ts:
        print("Time is of type {0} in the DataFrame".format(type(elem))            
df.begin_ts = df.begin_ts.dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Output:

```
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'datetime.datetime'> in the table
Time is of type <type 'unicode'> in the DataFrame
Time is of type <type 'unicode'> in the DataFrame
Time is of type <type 'unicode'> in the DataFrame
```

I get the following error in the last line of my DataFrame code:

**Attribute Error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values**

***Edit: Resolved by passing in a column as the parse_dates parameter in read_sql_query() ***

Comment: Hard to say anything without looking at data. can you create  [MCVE] ?

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `parse_dates ` parameter in the `read_sql_query` function? From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html): "List of column names to parse as dates., 
Dict of {column_name: format string}

Comment: The data that I'm using is my first chunk of code. That's the table that's being query-ed. In the SQL table it is a datetime object but somehow after being added to the DataFrame it is a Unicode object. That is what my question is, how come it's been converted to a Unicode object instead of the standard Pandas.TimeStamp Object? @harvpan

Comment: That worked, thank you @G.Anderson